# recreate .idea/workspace.yml in RubyMine

Tags: rubymine

I have a file conflict with my co-worker in .idea/workspace.yml. I mistakenly deleted my version, and his Ubuntu version of this file is not compatible in my OSX.

Is there a way to recreate .idea/workspace.yml from my RubyMine IDE without resorting to Git to get back original version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Local History](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/local-history.html) feature to restore files inside RubyMine. Note that this file should be normally [excluded from the version control](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186).